# realsense sdk2 example error

Tags: visual-studio, window, realsense

I'm using intel realsense SDK2.10.0 with D410 depth module to build a project. But faced with an immediate problem that I can't run even the hello world example they give us. With no problem is building the project, there is always internal error as:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB60434008 in hello-world.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: rs2::error at memory location 0x000000B0AD1EF670.

This is my first-time use visual studio so that could be a naive problem but I can't identify it. Any help and idea?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. The point is that those samples didn't expect infrared image as input and the render code part is for RGB frames. I only have the depth module with the infrared camera with no RGB sensor. so the sample program can't handle it.

You have to heavily modify the example.hpp file to make it functional. So if you are not a professional user, don't try individual modules on your own, or at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use Windows CMAKE tool to configure the build x64 environment for VS2015.
The CMAKE tool will help create the required librealsense VS projects for you to build those RealSense sample apps.

BR,
Freeman

Comment: Thanks for your help but really the problem lies deeper.